# How to find just the size of maximum Clique of a graph without actually bothering about the vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

I know that finding the Maximum clique of a graph is NP-Complete. However, is there a fast algorithm or trick exists which would allow me to just calculate the Clique number of a graph without actually bothering about what are those vertices?

> Also, does it make any difference, if the graph has some special
>   properties? For example, if the graph is known only to have triangles
>   as building blocks or no cycles at all. In other words, there would
>   not be any cycle which does not have an embedded triangle inside.

**P.S.** I have not written any code to start with as it would be pointless to try and solve and NP-complete problem. However, as this problem is a common problem, and if there exists a faster algorithm which gives me only the Clique number of a graph, I would like to understand that algorithm first then I will try to do some hands on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding just the clique number is also NP-hard.

If a graph is chordal (which is perhaps what you mean in the other question) then the maximal clique can be found in polynomial time by traversing the perfect elimination order.

Comment: perfect elimination order? Could you please give an example? thanks.

Comment: Search for chordal graph in any book on graph theory or even wikipedia.

Comment: Got it, thanks.